# How can I locate an image part's coordinates in a big image?

Tags: c#, algorithm, image, image-processing

I found this on the internet and examined source codes. a program for locating licence plates in an image. check from here source codes are available and you can compile it.

http://translate.google.com.tr/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=tr&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=tr&tl=en&u=http://www.atasoyweb.net/blog/goruntu-isleme-k6s0/arac-plakasi-konum-tespiti-y109.html

but I want do something different but should be work like this. what I am trying to do is, locating a specific part in an image and getting coordinates of it. here is an example:

http://postimage.org/image/a60idjok/

Comment: You should try it and then ask more specific questions if you have some troubles. Note also that finding exactly the same image should be a lot easier than finding image showing similar thing (e.g. license plate).

Comment: I don't know anything about this never worked anything related to image recognation or pattern search. I'm also thinking the same it should be more easy but can't find anything similiar on the net so far.

Comment: Perhaps looking for something on the internet isn't the _first_ thing to do when you need to solve some problem. (But then, I may be just getting old.)

Comment: By the example given in the second link, the question is clear enough. Voting to reopen.

Comment: never mind. i found the solution and it's working very well.

Comment: any sampel code about solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform an [image correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_image_correlation).

Example in Mathematica:
[image]